# Statement for contradiction

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that for all $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $f(x)=0$ a.e.(almost everywhere) in $\Omega$. Then what is the statement which contradicts to the above statement? Is the following statement correct?

There exists $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$ a.e. in $\Omega$.

Comment: Not quite, since a function can fail to be 0 a.e. and also fail to be nonzero a.e.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful example. The correct statement should be: There exist $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the measure of $f(x)\neq 0$ a.e. in $\Omega$ is great than zero. Right?

Comment: Except for the a.e. part, that's looking better!